# UnicodeDecodeError when trying to read docx file

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, python-unicode

Error occurs when opening docx file using python 3

When I tried to run:

```
file=open("jinuj.docx","r",encoding="utf-8").read()
```

below error occured

```
    319         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    320         data = self.buffer + input
--> 321         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    322         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    323         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb6 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

Comment: A docx-file is a zipped bundle of xml-files. So since it isn't even text it surely isn't UTF-8 encoded....

Comment: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python-docx` can open a document from a so-called file-like `object`. It can also save to a file-like object:

```
from docx import Document
f = open('jinuj.docx', 'rb')
document = Document(f)
f.close()
```

**OR**

```
with open('jinuj.docx', 'rb') as f:
    source_stream = StringIO(f.read())
document = Document(source_stream)
source_stream.close()
```

[**Docs**](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html)